# Make monit wait longer before thinking something is dead

Tags: monit

I'm trying to start a program (Resque) but it takes a bit of time before a pidfile is written. Thus, I think that Monit thinks the program hasn't started and starts one or two more programs  before the before the pidfile of the first one is written.

How do I delay the time Monit checks again, just for this process? Or should I solve this in another way?

Comment: I added a new answer below. Although waiting longer between checks will prevent collisions for slow services, it can be a really bad experience for customers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How do I delay the time Monit checks again, just for this process?**

---

What you are trying to achieve could be done via "*SERVICE POLL TIME*" feature of monit

Monit documentation says

> Services are checked in regular intervals given by the

```
set daemon n
```

> statement. Checks are performed in the same order as they are written
>   in the .monitrc file, except if dependencies are setup between
>   services, in which case the services hierarchy may alternate the order
>   of the checks.

One of the method to customize service poll is

1. custom interval based on poll cycle length multiple

EVERY [number] CYCLES

Example:

```
check process resque with pidfile /your/app/root/tmp/pid/resque.pid
   every 2 cycles
```

**Or should I solve this in another way?**

---

I also did initial attempt to monitor resque jobs with monit because monit is a very lightweight daemon but eventually settled with GOD. I know , I know GOD is more resource hungry in comparison to monit but in case of resque we found it to be a good match.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using every x cycles. I just found the number that worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

You can check a specific service on a different interval than the default...

See [SERVICE POLL TIME](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-POLL-TIME) in the Monit documentation.

An example for your Resque program would be to check on a different number of cycles:

```
check process resque with pidfile /var/run/resque.pid
   every 5 cycles
```

or from the examples section:

```
Some servers are slow starters, like for example Java based Application Servers. 
So if we want to keep the poll-cycle low (i.e. < 60 seconds) but allow some services to take its time to start, 
the every statement is handy:

 check process dynamo with pidfile /etc/dynamo.pid every 2 cycles
       start program = "/etc/init.d/dynamo start"
       stop program  = "/etc/init.d/dynamo stop"
       if failed port 8840 then alert
```

or you can leverage the cron-style checks.

```
check process resque with pidfile /var/run/resque.pid
   every 10 * * * *
```

or if you're experiencing a slow startup, you can extend the timeout in the service start command:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/httpd.pid
       start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start" with timeout 90 seconds
```

Comment: Same answer, right?

Comment: `with timeout 90 seconds` was exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Kudos for including timeouts and cron-style.  This is the most accurate and complete answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can also check if something has failed for X times straight:

```
 if failed 
    port 80 
    for 10 cycles 
 then alert
```

Or for X times within Y polls:

```
 if failed 
    port 80
    for 3 times within 5 cycles 
 then alert
```

Or both:

```
 check filesystem rootfs with path /dev/hda1
  if space usage > 80% for 5 times within 15 cycles then alert
  if space usage > 90% for 5 cycles then exec '/try/to/free/the/space'
```

([from here](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#failure_tolerance))

Comment: This is another very good answer, as it shows how you can check on the default interval, but only take action on a more forgiving basis.

Answer (score 2):

A member of my team came up with a rather clever solution that **allows monit to check frequently (every minute)**, but once it has attempted to restart the service (which takes ~10 minutes) it **will wait a specified grace period before attempting to start again.**

This prevents waiting too long between checks, which combined with slow start is a much larger impact to customers.  It works by using an intermediate script that acts as flag to indicate monit is already taking action from the last failure.

```
check host bamboo with address bamboo.mysite.com
   if failed
           port 443 type tcpSSL protocol http
           and status = 200
           and request /about.action
            for 3 cycles
   then exec "/bin/bash -c 'ps -ef | grep -v "$$" | grep -v "grep" | grep restartBamboo.sh >/dev/null 2>&1; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then /opt/monit/scripts/restartBamboo.sh; fi'"
```

If bamboo (slow starting web app) is down for 3 minutes in a row, restart, BUT only if a restart script is not already running.

The the script that is called has a specified sleep that waits LONGER then the slowest start time for the service (in our case we expect to finish in ~10, so we sleep for 15)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Retarting bambo by calling init.d"
/etc/init.d/bamboo stop
echo "Stopped completed, calling start"
/etc/init.d/bamboo start
echo "Done restarting bamboo, but it will run in background for sometime before available so, we are sleeping for 15 minutes"
sleep 900
echo "done sleeping"
```

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Monit (5.16) supports a timeout for the start scripts with the syntax:

```
 <START | STOP | RESTART> [PROGRAM] = "program"
    [[AS] UID <number | string>]
    [[AS] GID <number | string>]
    [[WITH] TIMEOUT <number> SECOND(S)]
```

The [docs](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-METHODS) state:

> In the case of a process check, Monit will wait up to 30 seconds for the start/stop action to finish before giving up and report an error. You can override this timeout using the TIMEOUT option.

Which is what the "timeout" value will do.

Comment: Extending the timeout works if the actual start takes a long time but in the original question it sounds like the program may have started quickly (i.e. returned) but did not write out the PID immediately. Is there a way to tell monit to not check the service for a specified time after the restart?

Comment: The `timeout` should apply to both starts and restarts. As far as I understand, it puts in a delay before Monit checks that its: a) running, b) the expected PID file is created and c) a process with the expected PID is currently running.

I had some issues getting it to work where the specified application was just a script that forked the real process then returned without knowing what was happening with the process. Getting it to work in this case was a pain.

Comment: what about the system is rebooted and starting the services ? is there any way to specify a initial delay, in seconds, for each check ? also the passive checks without start/stop statements

Comment: I believe in that case you might be looking for `START DELAY`.